# R: Why does assignment of names attribute fail on objects retrieved with get()?

Tags: r, attributes, variable-assignment

R seems to treat assignment of the names attribute to an R object retrieved with get() as though it was the nonexistent get<- function instead of the names<- function.

```
> aa <-1:2
> bb <- "aa"
> get(bb)
[1] 1 2
> names(get(bb)) <- c("d", "e")
Error in names(get(bb)) <- c("d", "e") : could not find function "get<-"
```

This is especially puzzling as:

```
do.call(`names<-`, list(get(bb), c("d", "e")))
```

which should be equivalent, works fine.

Documentation of names says it is a primitive but not a special, unless I am meant to take "This is clearly necessary for ... the assignment operators" in R Internals as adequate documentation.

Comment: You don't need the `do.call`, just  `'names<-'(get(bb), c("d", "e"))` should work fine

Comment: It is not so much that the object is retrieved with get.  This works: `zz = get(bb)
names(zz) <- c("d", "e")`

Comment: @G5W I believe both you and the original question author are missing quotes around the `bb` in `get(bb)` in your code snippets; should be `get('bb')`.

Comment: It works for me without the quotes

Comment: @KeithHughitt OP wants to assign names for `aa`, not `bb`. And the value of `bb` is just `"aa"`, so `get(bb)` should be fine.

Comment: @kitman0804 Ah got it. I think I misunderstood the original intention. Thanks for clarifying!